# Extending Mage_Core_Model_Cache, cannot getModel inside constructor?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Here's more or less the code I'm working on:

```
class My_Model extends Mage_Core_Model_Cache
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'MYCACHE';
    const TYPE_INDEX = 'my_index';
    const COMPRESSION_PREFIX = 'CMP';
    const STATS_MODE = false;

    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
       $configOptions = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('global/mycache/options');

       $config = Mage::getModel('mymodel/cache')->getConfig(); // return false

        if ($configOptions) {
            $configOptions = $configOptions->asArray();
        } else {
            $configOptions = array();
        }
        $options = array_merge($configOptions, $options);
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function saveCache($data, $tags, $lifetime)
    {
        $config = Mage::getModel('mymodel/cache')->getConfig(); // return object
        ...
    }
}
```

So I can't get my model inside the constructor, it returns false.
But I'm be able to get inside `saveCache` method.

Why can't I get my model inside the constructor? I've tried make static method too in my model and try to call it directly inside constructor it returns false, but succeed if I call it inside `saveCache` method.

Comment: Are you sure it's your model that's returning false, not the getConfig method?

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth yes sir it returns false, like i explained in my question if i call it inside saveCache method it runs ok returning the object. do you know why? and is there any work around on this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could debug the `getModel()` method in `Mage.php` to see what's going on when it tries to instantiate that model.  Maybe the class alias hasn't been loaded into the magento config at that point yet. That method gets the config object and then calls `getModelInstance()`.  Follow the yellow brick road.